# Load c++ dll in Azure function 2x

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

I'm using Azure Function 2x with NetCore for my business and `c++ dll` needs to be embedded. I try to use Azure Function 1x everything ok but in 2x my system  through  `MyDll, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid`. Therefore, How I embed c++ DLL in Azure Function 2x

PS: I loaded DLL ok with NetCore 3.0 in ConsoleApp. But when I import Azure SDK function still error.

Comment: Hi, Azure Function v2 not support multilingual environment since last June. Take a look of the announcement: https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129

Answer (score 0):

Now, we need to use Single language in Azure Function v2, because the Offical had made a breaking changes since last June. In that Function v2 update, the Official removed the ability to run multiple languages ​​in a single Function application.

Take a look of the [announcement](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129).

Going forward, all functions within a Function app must be written in the same language. (Note that v1 Function apps will not be affected by this.)

So If you want to use multilingual environment, you still have to use Function v1. Multilingualism in V2 and the further version is impossible.